# Regex for nginx route matching

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to match the following route:

`/{anything1}/{anything2}/file.{jpg|png}`

where `anything1` can be `[a-z0-9]` (lowercase letters and digits) and `anything2` can be `[-a-z0-9]` (lowercase letters, digits and a dash).

The reason why I don't want to match all the files like so:

`location ~* (.+)\.(jpg|png)$`

Is that I need `$anything1` and `$anything2` variables available in the `location` block so I can do a rewrite later on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You just enumerate facts, there is no question to answer.

Comment: the question is "How do I construct the regex to match `/{anything1}/{anything2}/file.{jpg|png}` route"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+\.(?:jpg|png)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lT49DX/2)

The `[^/]+` matches 1+ chars other than `/`, and thus cannot overflow across `/` delimiters and assures you only match paths with a certain number of subpaths.

The dot must be escaped, hence `\.` is used.

The `(?:jpg|png)` is an *alternation group* that matches 2 sequences, either `jpg` or `png`.

If you indeed want to only allow specific characters (a whitelisting approach), you would need to use *quantifiers* (I think you need `+`, *one or more occurrences*) with your character classes for the *anything* parts:

```
^/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9-]+/[^/]*\.(?:png|jpg)$
```